# Codeigniter: Submit without reloading issue?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to submit without reloading using AJAX, but when I press the Submit Button and no records are insert, however it prints out that All records are Submitted. Any Idea

```
 <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
        <?php echo form_open('', 'class="form-horizontal" id="myForm"'); ?>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="note_text" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Note</label>
               <div class="col-sm-10">
                 <textarea class="form-control" name="note_text" rows="3"></textarea>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Post</button>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="buttons"> <span id="error" style="display:none; color:#F00">Some Error!Please Fill form Properly </span> <span id="success" style="display:none; color:#0C0">All the records are submitted!</span>
        </form>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myForm').on('submit',function(e) {

  $.ajax({
     url:'',
     data:$(this).serialize(),
     type:'POST',
     success:function(data){
       console.log(data);
       $("#success").show().fadeOut(5000); //=== Show Success Message==
     },
     error:function(data){
       $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000); //===Show Error Message====
     }
     });
     e.preventDefault(); //=== To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"===
    });
    });
   </script>
```

Also can someone **point me** to a tutorial about how to do LIVE UPDATE. I mean this function for example is in index() where is also my loop for all the notes and what I am searching for is as soon as I submit it and immediately the new record of notes to be shown below. Something like Facebook posting

Comment: Why your URL is empty ? And you should place "e.preventDefault();" just after the submit handler.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if I put the full path there or leave it empty. also the function index() is where the save is going to be executed. I put the e.prevent after the submit handler and still nothing is happening :(

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is in your server side code, it's returning a HTTP 200 response so the $.ajax function thinks it succeeded but actually it didn't. This might happen if you're catching the error and outputting a message, but not throwing say a 500 error.

If you have google chrome press F12 to bring up developer tools > Go to network > Press submit and a new entry should appear in the list > click on that entry. Take note of the "Status Code" in the headers tab, and the output in the response tab.

If that doesn't return what you'd expect (ie. non-200 when the update fails and the correct response) then you should start debugging your server side code.

Comment: It's strange. When I press the submit button and I get 2 entries, both pointing to the same file. The first one is 302 with Requested Method: POST and the other one is 200 with Requested Method: GET, but I haven't set a GET method nowhere...

Comment: ***If I press the submit button twice then it submits cause it is pointing to the method but if only click it once it doesn't work ?!***

Comment: Is the "Location" field in 302 response headers the same as the GET Request URL? 302 is a redirect. Is there anything in your code or your HTTP server configuration which might cause a redirect?

Comment: yeah I had redirect after It saves. I removed it now and it doesn't show but in order to submit it and save it I must press Submit button twice ...

Comment: maybe is because of this. The form validation ?                                                             if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
    $this->parser->parse('admin/template_admin', $data);
   }
   else
   {
    $createNote->save();
   }